# How to repeating a String in Ruby one or multiple times

Tags: ruby

How do I repeat a String in Ruby one or multiple times?

```
def repeat(*args)
  str, second_arg, count = "", args[1], 1
   if args[1] == nil
     args[1] = 1
   end
    while second_arg >= count
      str += args[0] + " "
      second_arg -= 1
    end

  return str
end
```

My outlined test is:

```
describe "repeat" do
    it "should repeat" do
      expect(repeat("hello")).to eq("hello hello")
    end

    # Wait a second! How can you make the "repeat" method
    # take one *or* two arguments?
    #
    # Hint: *default values*
    it "should repeat a number of times" do
      expect(repeat("hello", 3)).to eq("hello hello hello")
    end
  end
```

If `argument[1]` is missing I want to fill it with the value "1" so it will at least return 1.

This is my error:

```
Failures:

  1) Simon says repeat should repeat
     Failure/Error: expect(repeat("hello")).to eq("hello hello")
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `>=' for nil:NilClass
     # ./lib/03_simon_says.rb:14:in `repeat'
     # ./spec/03_simon_says_spec.rb:39:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: What's wrong with `def repeat(str, count = 2) str * count end`?

Comment: @JörgWMittag you beat me to it. On side note as it stands now (i.e. default args[1] to 1) `repeat` without a count will not "repeat" because `1-1 =0` so the while loop will end.

Comment: There's absolutely no reason to use a *Variable-Length Argument List* here. It's slower, it's more code, and it's less clear.

Answer (score 3):

Here `if args[1] == nil` you're validating if the second value in `ARGV` is `nil` and setting it as `1`, but then, in your `while` statement you're working with `second_arg`, which already has taken the value for `args[1]`, so, most probably it won't pass your validation in:

```
if args[1] == nil
  args[1] = 1
end
```

You could try setting `second_arg` variable inside that validation, instead setting `args[1]`:

```
if args[1] == nil
  second_arg = 1
end
```

Also "*any statement in Ruby returns the value of the last evaluated expression*", so you can put just `str` as the last value in your `repeat` method and this will be evaluated as the return value.

Answer (score 2):

You're totally over-complicating this. There's no need to use a Variable-Length Argument List here. It's slower, it's more code, and it's less clear. The test code says it itself: "Hint: *default values*"

```
def repeat(str, count = 2)
    Array.new(count, str).join(" ")
end
```

Which is a more elegant way of representing looping like:

```
def repeat(str, count = 2)
    result = str
    
    (0..count).each { result += " " + str }
    
    result
end
```

Comment: Not sure who downvoted this, but it's exactly the first thing that came to my mind.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but maybe because of the lack of Ruby verbosity in the code. You can see the unneeded return in a one-line method definition, the for loop, the +=, the + for concatenation, etc.

Comment: @SebastianPalma Have you noticed what is says right above that code? "Or if you prefer to manually loop it:". That code is demonstrative of what `join` does.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `args[1]` before you set `second_arg`.

```
def repeat(*args)
    args[1] = 1 if args[1] == nil
    str, second_arg, count = "", args[1], 1

    while second_arg >= count
      str += args[0] + " "
      second_arg -= 1
    end

    return str
end
```

You can also use the conditional assignment operator instead:

```
# The two lines do the same thing
args[1] = 1 if args[1] == nil
args[1] ||= 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"hello" * 5 # => "hellohellohellohellohello"

Array.new(5, "hello").join(" ") # => "hello hello hello hello hello"
```